# What is the name for fixed metal venetian blinds?

Tags: heat-pump, rain, wind

I am about to build a canopy/enclosure for heat pump outdoor unit to protect it from strong wind and angle rain. It needs to cover the unit all around but still allow free air flow.

Ideally the walls of such an enclosure would be made of metal "venetian blind" panels that are fixed/unmovable. The panels would look like this but without the ropes:

[image]

Is there a common name for such panels under which they are available on the market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities come to mind :

Louvered panels,

slatted panels,

slatted ventilation panels.

A google search for the text below gave many from 4" by 4" to fencing and all types in between.

[slatted ventilation panels](https://www.google.com/search?channel=crow&q=slatted%20ventilation%20panels&tbm=isch&source=univ&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIkpb4u6niAhUM3aQKHcQcA04Q7Al6BAgIEA0&biw=1095&bih=803)